# Python Polars read database command giving error

Tags: python-polars

I am running the simple query from python lambda code.Query needs to run on postgres database . Getting errors while using the where clause . This is not sqlalchemy connection.
A simple query is running fine .

```
 df = pl.read_database(
            query="SELECT * FROM <schema>.<table name> WHERE col1 = :value",
            execute_options={"parameters": {"value": 1}},
            connection=conn
        )
```

> 2024-02-08 13:47:32,358 [ERROR] [Trace id
> =69f062ad-1b6a-418d-ba54-b2dc02ae035d] - {"errorType": "SyntaxError", "errorMessage": "syntax error at or near ":"\nLINE 1: ...T * FROM
> . WHERE contact_id = :value\n
> ^\n", "stackTrace": ["Traceback (most recent call last):\n", "  File
> "C:\GIT\lambdas\peopleSearch.py", line 84, in lambda_handler\n
> df = pl.read_database(\n         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n", "  File
> "C:\GIT\venv\\Lib\site-packages\polars\io\database.py", line
> 582, in read_database\n    return cx.execute(\n
> ^^^^^^^^^^^\n", "  File
> "C:\GIT\venv\Lib\site-packages\polars\io\database.py", line
> 350, in execute\n    result = cursor_execute(query,
> *positional_options)\n             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^\n",
> "psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near ":"\nLINE 1:
> ...T * FROM . WHERE contact_id = :value\n
> ^\n\n"]}

Comment: Try this 


df = pl.read_database(
    query="SELECT * FROM <schema_name>.<table_name> WHERE col1 = %s",
    execute_options={"parameters": [1]},
    connection=conn
)

Comment: that is really good. if it works I should post the answer so that someone will use it

Comment: Please go ahead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
df = pl.read_database( 
    query="SELECT * FROM <schema_name>.<table_name> WHERE col1 = %s", 
    execute_options={"parameters": [1]}, 
    connection=conn 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL uses the `$1`, `$2`, ... syntax for parameter placeholders, not the named parameter style like `:value`.

You could instead try the following.

```py
df = pl.read_database(
    query="SELECT * FROM <schema>.<table name> WHERE col1 = $1",
    execute_options={"parameters": (1,)},
    connection=conn,
)
```